# Stylish / Stylus : A:visited and A:link only affects certain websites

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, stylish

✨ I am using the Chrome extensions Stylish and Stylus for the first time which use C programming language.

My goal is to use this in forum websites like Reddit and DeviantArt forums so I know which forum posts I have read or not. By default, without the Stylish or Stylus extensions, DeviantArt nor Gaia Online does not Mark the forum posts as read or unread with color.

My code is simple:

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix("https://www.deviantart.com/forum/community/projects/"),
domain("toyhou.se"),
url-prefix("https://www.chickensmoothie.com/Forum/viewforum.php?f=121"),
url-prefix("reddit.com"),
url-prefix("https://forums.furaffinity.net/forums/art-exchange/"),
url-prefix("https://www.gaiaonline.com/forum/art-freebies/f.108/") {
    A:visited {
        color: magenta
    }
    A:link {
        color: cyan
    }
}
```

Sites the code works in (links are colored):

https://reddit.com

https://toyhou.se

https://www.chickensmoothie.com/Forum/viewforum.php?f=121

https://forums.furaffinity.net/forums/art-exchange/

Sites the code **does not work** in (no colored links):

https://www.gaiaonline.com/forum/art-freebies/f.108/

https://www.deviantart.com/forum/community/projects/

I’m wondering how I can get links colored accordingly for the sites that the code does not work in. In the end, I need code that will color the links. Thank you! ✨

Comment: Add `!important` at the end of each color. More info in [Stylus wiki](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus/wiki/Writing-styles#overwriting-page-styles).

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried this already and saved the file but no dice

Comment: I guess you didn't add it correctly or there's another problem e.g. maybe another extension overrides the style. This works for me: `color: magenta !important` and `color: cyan !important`